# How to connect female audio jack with breadboard

Tags: pinout, plug

[image]

[image]

I need to connect this female audio jack to a breadboard, and then to an amplifier and converter. I don't know the pinout of this component and the GND, can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you plug in a connector and measure?

Answer (score 1):

The five leads suggests to me that it's a stereo (not mono) jack connector, and that both primary audio conductors have a "normaling" connection which provides a signal when there is no cable plugged in. A stereo connector would also be called TRS -- tip, ring, and sleeve (referring to the three metal components of the plug, separated by the black insulating rings).

On normaling: When the plug is inserted, the connectors are pushed away from the normaling leads; when the plug is removed, springs force them back into contact. You can use these to e.g. hold your speaker at silence (vs random static) when no cable is inserted.

See more info here: https://northcoastsynthesis.com/news/all-about-normalling/ -- my guess is you've got something more like the image for J2 in the 2nd picture, but no normaling lead for the longest of the conductors (i.e., no pin #5). The leads with the `->` on the end are the normaling connectors. The leads with the little `^` signify the indentation that makes contact with the actual audio cable plug. So going by that J2 symbol's schematic, your goal is to find which leads go to pins 1, 3, and 6 (and you have no pin "5").

Also as a technicality, there is no defined "ground" pin for a connector like this. By convention, the sleeve (rear-most) conductor on the TRS cable plug is held at the reference ground for the signals on tip and ring, but that is not a property imposed physically by the cable or the jack. Also, you probably want to connect sleeve to ground when you are *sending* audio but you should leave the sleeve pin floating if you are *receiving* audio from a device plugged into the wall, so you don't create a ground loop. You want GND to be tied together only via the outlet in your wall. If you're making a battery-powered audio receiver, then connecting the GNDs together does make sense.

Based on its physical layout my *guess* is that orange is the Tip, black is Tip-Normal (or vice versa), blue is Ring, white is Ring-normal (or vice versa), and green is Sleeve. But you can verify it with this procedure:

OK, with that context out of the way, let's get to work. Do you have a multimeter? If not, get one first. Set it to resistance mode, on a low setting (200Ohm or 1kOhm).

You will also need a voltage source. A 9V battery will do in a pinch, a benchtop power supply would be better.

- Leave the jack unplugged from anything, and connect the multimeter leads to each possible pair of leads (orange+blue, orange+black, blue+black, etc). For most of these your multimeter should be reporting "no connection" or the off-scale-high value. If the resistance drops to a few mOhm, then that pair is connected and you've identified one conductor and its normaling companion. Write each of those pairs down. Ohmmeter mode is omnidirectional -- just a connectivity test -- so the red and the black probes can be attached to either side of a potential connected pair and you'll get the same measurement.
- If you have five leads, my guess is that the sleeve will not have a normaling pin.
- Work through all your possibilities in order and you'll eventually find two pairs that are connected and the fifth one totally free.
- If it appears that you have three pins connected together, check your measurements, then your soldering. That would be surprising and likely a mistake.

Your next goal is to determine for each pair which is the "true" lead and which is the normaling one, and which true lead goes to each of tip, ring, and sleeve.

Get a cheap short stereo audio cable (a foot is more than enough) and cut off one of the plugs. Open a few inches of insulation up (carefully!) with an exacto knife. Inside there should be three insulated wires; pull an inch or so of each wire out, and strip a few mm of the insulation off the end of each wire and separate them so they're not touching. Now repeat ohmmeter measurements: identify which wire goes to each of the tip, ring, and sleeve of the remaining plug. Each wire should have (close to) 0 Ohm resistance to exactly one of the T, R, and S on the plug. Remember which wire is which; mark them T, R, and S with a piece of tape or something.

Now you can establish which lead is which on the jack itself.

- Plug the good end of your decapitated cable into the jack under test.
- Turn on your power supply at some reasonable low voltage (3V or 5V is plenty).
- Set your multimeter to measure voltage at the appropriate scale and turn it on.
- Connect the GND (black) lead of your power supply to the GND (black) lead of your multimeter by binding the alligator clips together.
- Attach the positive (red) lead of your power supply to one of the 3 wires inside the cable. You should have marked this as being one of tip, ring, and sleeve.
- Touch the positive (red) probe from your multimeter to each of the leads you have soldered to your connector. Whichever one is at the same voltage as your power supply is the lead you care about.
- Repeat til you've found all 3 of tip, ring, and sleeve.
- From the ohmmeter measurements done up top, you now also know which are the normaling connections for each of tip and ring. Those will *not* show a voltage when the plug is inserted.

Comment: "but you should leave the sleeve pin floating if you are *receiving* audio from a device plugged into the wall, so you don't create a ground loop." – Leaving the sleeve pin unconnected may cause more problems than it solves. If the L and R signals are coming in through the audio cable, but the reference (ground) is coming in through the household wiring, then all of the emf induced on that loop is going to show up as noise. Connecting the sleeve pin to your ground will get rid of that noise, but the resulting current may cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the best thing to do with the sleeve pin is probably to treat it as the negative side of a differential pair, and use it as an inverting input to whatever thing you're putting the signal into.

Comment: thank you for response, sorry for Information is not accurate i make update for post ,so i want to connect this electrodes to collectect data from EEG signal (Electroencephalography) ,i take idea from this example of ECG monitor https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmicrocontrollerslab.com%2Fad8232-ecg-module-pinout-interfacing-with-arduino-applications-features%2F&psig=AOvVaw34l9BuIJXtfADnaOe7NFiG&ust=1681723451055000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCLC9qpmKrv4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ